# ignore point on split \\w+

Tags: java, split

OK so I don't know if it was already answered and it might be pretty easy but I'm kind of stuck on this I have a formatted string that contains information about players it look like this

```
<Lindstrom195, zillah, 13, Oacoma699, Maxville505, Mazie999, Pawnee966>
```

and to get all of the information I use split like this

```java
String s = "<Lindstrom195, zillah, 13, Oacoma699, Maxville505, Mazie999, Pawnee966>";
String[] words;

words = s.split("\\W+");
```

every thing was fine until I get on this player

```
<S.N.P.J.972, theodore, 44, Roscoe515, Okolona536, Sixes960>
```

the fact that he get dot in his nick name make my method fail so,
How is there a way to use split with \w+ but make it ignore dots ?

I tried this insted but it failed

```java
String s = "<Lindstrom195, zillah, 13, Oacoma699, Maxville505, Mazie999, Pawnee966>";
String[] words;

words = s.split("<|,|>|\\s+");
\\ it fail because it put empty element in my String[]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the \W means any non-word character, but you want to split on any non-word character except for '.', so the syntax for that is :

```
words = s.split("[\\W&&[^.]]+");
```

As with your original answer, this will result in an empty first element due to the initial "<" in the input string.

Comment: ho ! thanks, you're right it need less modification in my code , I really need to learn more about regex but I can't find good pages anywhere. Anyway thank you

Comment: Java's regex is given in the Pattern pages : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html .  I know what you mean about tutorials, especially since there are so many variants.  For example, one common trap where Java differs from most other engines is that `Pattern.matches("3+", "123345")` returns false (since it implicitly applies to the whole string - so it's effectively doing `"^3+$"`).  https://ryanstutorials.net/regular-expressions-tutorial/ looks a good plain english introduction for general regex.

Answer (score 0):

To ignore split on regex, do this:

```
    s=s.substring(1,s.length()-1);
    String[] words;
    words=s.split(",\\s");
```

Comment: Hi.  have you viewed my answer?

Comment: Ok.  did you want to do something with mine since it worked without your having to do anything with the array?